# how to add title in react select option value <Div> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-select

I want to add title on React-select box options value dynamically, I am using react-select library in this.

**Code :**

```
 import * as React from 'react'; import Select from 'react-select';
 import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
 import { QUICK_FILTER_TYPES } from '../../constants';
 import { setQuickFilters } from '../../redux/actions';
 import reactSelectStyles from '../../styles/react-select-styles';
 import { IValueLabelTitleObject } from '../../typedefs/interfaces';

 const **options** = [ QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.STALE_RTS,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.MISSING_RTS, QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.STALE_DPUL,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.MISSING_DPUL,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.STALE_DELIVERY_FORECAST,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.MISSING_DELIVERY_FORECAST,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.LATE_DELIVERIES, QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.UPCOMING_RTS,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.UPCOMING_DPUL,
     QUICK_FILTER_TYPES.UPCOMING_DELIVERIES,
 ].map(v => ({ value: v, label: v, title: v })); 

 <Select
     isMulti menuIsOpen name="quick-filter-select"
     onChange={selectedValues => props.dispatch(
     setQuickFilters(selectedValues as IValueLabelTitleObject[]) ) }
     **options={options}** placeholder="Quick filters"
     styles={reactSelectStyles()} value={props.quickFilters} />
```

**Automatically it add the Div has been made in the option tag**

> Stale RTS

Comment: Can you add your code in https://codesandbox.io/ for more help?

Comment: actually i just wanted to add title box in the select box, can we do that using select attributes or onfocus function , i cannot add in the sandbox

Comment: React-select accept an array of objects contain value and label

Comment: @Madhur What do you mean by title,please clarify.

Comment: I just want to show Tooltip while hovering to the option tag (but if i add title into this from inspect element it  has show tooltip) but i dont know how it will do tht

Answer (score 2):

Seems like below code snippet can help you out.

```
const Option = (props) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip content={'Customise your option component!'} truncateText>
      <components.Option {...props}/>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{ Option }}
    options={options}
  />
);
```

For more details read the react-select documentation on custom options [document](https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components)

Comment: yes from given document it has working properly. there was some issue with some files we need to include which concurring error. now resolved

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `components` is imported from `'react-select'`. `i.e. import { components } from 'react-select'`

Comment: In case you want to use some field of your option object as text of the tooltip, you can extract it from the props object, e.g. content={props["data"]["Description"]}.